# Javascript submit button URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-steps

I am using Free Bootstrap Wizard. https://www.bootstrapdash.com/product/free-bootstrap-wizard/#product-demo-section

wizard code http://www.jquery-steps.com

Trying to redirect the user to register-success.html page after click finish button.

Here is my JS:

```
//Wizard Init

$("#wizard").steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "section",
    transitionEffect: "none",
    stepsOrientation: "vertical",
    titleTemplate: '<span class="number">#index#</span>'

});
```

[finish button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbADL.png)

Comment: Please explain exactly what you are achieving and try to include your html code so we can match it up to your javascript. Thank you.

Comment: Trying to redirect the user to register-success.html page after click finish button.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to redirect to success page. but not sure if the solution is correct

```
$("#wizard").steps({
headerTag: "h3",
bodyTag: "section",
transitionEffect: "none",
stepsOrientation: "vertical",
titleTemplate: '<span class="number">#index#</span>',
labels: {
    finish: "Create My Accout",
},
onFinished: function redirect() {
    window.location.replace("register-success.html");
    return false;
}
```

});